# Query Regarding the Proof of Z(SO(2m))={±1} in Section 3.7 of 'Naive Lie Theory' by John Stillwell

Tags: lie-groups, general-linear-group

I have been reading John Stillwell's 'Naive Lie Theory' and in Section 3.7, the author tries to prove that $Z(SO(2m)) = {\pm 1}$. In the proof, a matrix $I^\star$ is introduced with the form:

$$ I^\star = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{matrix} \right) $$

and it's mentioned that a diagonal arrangement of $I^\star$ is in $SO(2m)$. However, when $m$ is odd, wouldn't the determinant of the matrix $I^\star$ be -1? By definition, matrices in $SO(2m)$ should have a determinant of 1. Is there an error in this part of the proof, or am I misunderstanding something? Any clarification would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you give more details about what a "diagonal arrangement" there is?

Comment: @DietrichBurde In the original text, it says

"build $I^\star_{2m}$ from copies of $I^\star$ on the diagonal"

And it mentions that for

$R_{\theta_1, \theta_2, \ldots, \theta_n}$ built from a sequence of $2 \times 2$ blocks (placed along the diagonal) of the form
$$
R_\theta=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{array}\right) .
$$

$R_{\theta_1, \theta_2, \ldots, \theta_n}$ will commute with $I_{2 m}^*$ only if each $\sin \theta_k=0$ and $\cos \theta_k= \pm 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I agree that there is a problem here, it is easy to go around it. The final goal is to prove that if $R_{\theta_1,\theta_2,\ldots,\theta_n}$ belongs to the center of $SO(2m)$, then each $\sin\theta_k$ is equal to $0$, right?! So, consider a block matrix $J$ whose blocs consist of $m-2$ copies of the identity matrix and two copies $I^*$, one of which is located at the same position as $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\cos\theta_k&-\sin\theta_k\\\sin\theta_k&\cos\theta_k\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Then $J\in SO(2m)$ and, since $R_{\theta_1,\theta_2,\ldots,\theta_n}$ and $J$ commute, $\sin\theta_k=0$.

Comment: Yes that’s correct! thank you for your clear answer!